Sufficient conditions for odd harmonics for periodic signals
We have a periodic signal given as $x (t) = x (t + T)$. Moreover, we also know that
$$x (t) = -x \left( t + \frac{T}{2} \right)$$
We need to show that $x (t)$ is odd harmonic; i.e., in the Fourier series representation, the even Fourier coefficients are zero. Here is my attempt at it.
Since
$$x (t) = -x \left(t + \frac{T}{2} \right)$$
we have
$$\sum_k a_k e^{j k \omega_0 t} = -\sum_k a_k (-1)^k e^{j k \omega_0 t}$$
This implies
$$2 \sum_k a_k e^{j k \omega_0 t} = 0$$
where $k$ is even. This is where I am stuck. Does my result imply $a_k$ is zero when $k$ is even?
Edits
Since
$$a_k = \frac{1}{T} \int_{T} x \left( t + \frac{T}{2} \right) e^{-j k \omega_0 t} dt$$
for all $k$, we have
$$\sum_k a_k e^{j k \omega_0 t} = \sum_k \frac{1}{T} \int_{T} x \left( t + \frac{T}{2} \right) dt$$
Help is appreciated.

It is straightforward once you write an explicit expression for $a_k$.

@K.Jiang Do you mean the Fourier analysis equation for $a_{k}$.
means my above approach is taking in wrong direction.

Yes. Your equations are not incorrect, per se, but using them you can arrive at expressions for $a_k$. Then you will find it very easy to show that $a_k = 0$ for even $k$.

@K.Jiang
I have tried to add some edits. can you kindly advise if that's what you are trying to hint at? thanx

The first equation looks good, except you should be more explicit about your limits of integration. You want to integrate over one full period. Then, use what you know about $x (t)$ to evaluate the integral for $k$ even.

@K.Jiang will you mind guiding me here? I do not know how to proceed with calculating values of $a_{k}$.
And regarding limits of integration, plz note that x(t) is an arbitrary signal.

I will post an answer. Note that $x (t)$ is not a truly arbitrary signal, as it satisfies periodicity $x (t + T) = x (t)$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Assume a periodic signal $x (t)$ with period $T$; i.e., $x (t + T) = x (t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The signal also satisfies $x \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right) = -x (t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that $x (t)$ is odd harmonic; i.e., even Fourier coefficients are zero. Define $\omega_0 = \frac{2 \pi}{T}$ as the fundamental frequency.
Let's start by writing an explicit expression for the Fourier coefficients. Since we are working with a real signal, it helps to think about series of the form
$$x (t) = A_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty A_n \cos (n \omega_0 t) + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty B_n \sin (n \omega_0 t)$$
(i.e., sinusoids rather than complex exponentials - the correspondence with the complex coefficients is $C_n = \frac{1}{2} (A_n - i B_n)$, as you can prove). We will need to pick an interval of length $T$ over which to integrate. Any one will do, which results in different values of $A_n, B_n$, but will not change the fact that $A_n = B_n = 0$ for all even $n$. So, pick an arbitrary one, call it $I$, and let $I'$ be the first half of $I$.
Here, $A_0 = \frac{1}{T} \int_I x (t) dt$ is just the average value of the signal. We have
$$A_0 = \frac{1}{T} \int_I x (t) dt = \frac{1}{T} \int_{I'} \left( x (t) + \underbrace{x \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right)}_{-x (t)} \right) dt$$
$$= \frac{1}{T} \int_{I'} 0 dt = 0$$
as expected.
For positive $n$, we have that
$$\begin{cases}
A_n = \frac{2}{T} \int_I x (t) \cos (n \omega_0 t) dt \\
B_n = \frac{2}{T} \int_I x (t) \sin (n \omega_0 t) dt
\end{cases}$$
Recall that $\omega_0 = \frac{2 \pi}{T} \implies \omega_0 T = 2 \pi$. When $n$ is a positive even integer; i.e., $n = 2 k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we therefore have that
$$\cos \left( n \omega_0 \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right) \right) = \cos (n \omega_0 t + 2 \pi k) = \cos (n \omega_0 t)$$
Therefore, we can say that $x \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right) \cos \left( n \omega_0 \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right) \right) = -x (t) \cos (n \omega_0 t)$. So, in a similar fashion as the $A_0$ coefficient, we have
$$A_n = \frac{2}{T} \int_I x (t) \cos (\omega_0 t) dt = \frac{2}{T} \int_{I'} \left( x (t) \cos (n \omega_0 t) + \underbrace{x \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right) \cos \left( n \omega_0 \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right) \right)}_{-x (t) \cos (n \omega_0 t)} \right) dt$$
$$= \frac{2}{T} \int_{I'} 0 dt = 0$$
What about the sine components with $n$ even? It is basically the same story, since
$$\sin \left( n \omega_0 \left( t + \frac{1}{2} T \right) \right) = \sin \left( n \omega_0 t + 2 \pi k \right) = \sin (n \omega_0 t)$$
which you can use to show that $B_n = 0$ for all even $n$.

thanks for the detailed explanation. it is quite helpful.

@jayant Great, glad that it was helpful.
